# Checking a solution of a PDE using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a differential equation and its solution but when I ask Mathematica to verify it I receive that this is not a solution. Is the code wrong or maybe there is a mistake in the solution?

```
ClearAll[f, z];
ode = 16 (C^2 - 1)^2 f''''[z] + (160 C (C^2 - 1)) f'''[z] - 
    8 ( C^2 (n^2 - 4 n - 46) - n^2 + 4 n + 22) f''[z] - 
    24 C (n^2 - 4 n - 6) f'[z] + (n - 4)^2 n^2 f[z] == 
   0; (*define the 4th order differential equation*)
func[z] = z (1 - 2 C z^2 + z^4)^(1/2)
Integrate[(4 C z^2 - 1)/(z^2 (z^4 - 2 C z^2 + 1)^(3/2)), 
  z]; (*define the function to check*)

If[Simplify[ode /. f -> (func[z] &)] === 
  True,(*check if the function satisfies the ODE*)
 Print["The function satisfies the given ODE."], 
 Print["The function does not satisfy the given ODE."]]
```

For reference: The differential equation is:

[image: Equation/Solution]

[image: Equation/Solution]

Comment: You have at least one typo in your expression for the differential equation; look carefully at the negative signs in front of the parentheses in each term. Also, are there any conditions on `c`? You also have syntax errors later on.  You can't do `ode /. f -> (func &)`, because `func &` doesn't know that `z` is the variable.

Comment: I changed a little bit but still I have the same problem. Could you detail why? The only condition is that C is not equal to +1 or - 1.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it with C -> k, and ode[f_] just a function of an expression in z to be checked for zero.

```
 ode[f_]: = 16 (k^2 - 1)^2 D[f,{z,4}] + (160 k(k^2 - 1)) D[f,{z,3}] -
 8 ( k^2 (n^2 - 4 n - 46) - n^2 + 4 n + 22)  D[f,{z,2}] - 
24 k (n^2 - 4 n - 6)  D[f,z] + (n - 4)^2 n^2 f  

func = Function@@ {{z}, z (1 - 2 k z^2 + z^4)^(1/2)*
Integrate[(4 k z^2 - 1)/(z^2 (z^4 - 2 k z^2 + 1)^(3/2)), z]}
```

But already the check at z=0 fails

```
ode[func[z]]/.z->0
```

or yielding a fourth order polynomial in k and n.

The normal way is to gather the rational over a common denominator, taking the Numerator and try to nullify all enties in the

```
CoefficientList[expr,z].
```